# Generics casting explanation needed

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Here are two forms to work with generics extending base type:

```
public abstract <T extends Runnable> BlockingQueue<T> getQueueA();
public abstract BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> getQueueB();
```

I don't understand. What is the difference? Both methods seem to return the same BlockingQueue of objects that extend Runnable.

Answer (score 3):

```
BlockingQueue<Thread> threads = thing.getQueueA(); // works

BlockingQueue<Thread> threads = thing.getQueueB(); // does not work
```

On the other side of things:

```
@Override public <T extends Runnable> BlockingQueue<T> getQueueA() {
    return new ArrayBlockQueue<Thread>(); // no worky
}
@Override public BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> getQueueB() {
    return new ArrayBlockQueue<Thread>(); // works
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although both return queues of a type that extends Runnable, the difference is that the first version is a *typed* method, and the type `T` is available inside the method and to the compiler so it may *infer* the type when the method is called.

The second version has none of these benefits: it merely returns a queue whose type is unknown, but extends Runnable.